# sp_executesql get xml return

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to execute a procedure that is encrypted and get the return(That is a XML) and add to a variable. I try with sp_executesql but don't sucess.

here's what a try:

```
declare @str nvarchar(max)
select @str ='';
dECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @result varchar(max)
SET @Params = N'@resultout varchar(max) OUTPUT'

select @str ='select @resultout = MyProcedure @pageIndex=0,@ascDesc=N''ASC'',@culture=N''pt-br'''
EXEC sp_executesql @str,
@Params,
@resultout=@result OUTPUT
select @result
```

What is wrong?

Comment: are you getting an error?  If so what is it?

Comment: The error might have something to do with variable @resultout not being declared.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '@pageIndex'.